# What's wrong with this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, web

```
var menu = {
        minibox: document.getElementById("hypt_opContainer"),
        miniboxoptions: [document.getElementById("hypt_op"),    
        document.getElementById("style_op"), document.getElementById("js_op")]
 };

Object.prototype = {
       toggleVisibility: function(e) {
           e.style.display = (e.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
       }
   };

menu.miniboxoptions[0].addEventListener("click", menu.minibox.toggleVisibility);
```

It doesn't do anything when I click the box.
 What is wrong?

Comment: Did you intend `menu.miniboxoptions[0]` or `menu.minibox` when you add the event listener?  Seems to me you'd want the listener on the box. Hard to tell without your mark up.

Comment: You could use a `document.getElementById` alias. That would reduce your code size significantly. For instance: `function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }`... and then just: `$('hypt_opContainer')`

Comment: As the answers point out, there are two issues with your code: 1. You are replacing `Object.prototype` instead of augmenting it, 2. You are misusing the `event` object in the click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues: not all browsers support `addEventListener` and parameter `e` in

```
toggleVisibility: function(e) {...
```

is not an element. It is an event object, so `e.srcElement` should do the trick with - again - most browsers. More:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Tip: Do never ever touch Object.prototype!

Comment: `e.target` is the correct event property. `e.srcElement` is a Microsoft proprietary property that is being phased out in IE9. For cross-browser support: `var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`

Comment: @Šime yep, regarding window.event it is even worse. Never found a way to express the power of Object.prototype in a few words, did you?

Comment: Every object inherits all properties of the Object.prototype object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it would be valid to create your prototype that way. The way it is written clearly has the intention of replacing the prototype instead of extending it.

I would write

```
Object.prototype.toggleVisibility = function(e) {
        e.style.display = (e.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
    };
```